# Limit groups a play is run on from the playbook source code

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

The goal is to limit the group of hosts a play inside a playbook is run on.
The below code doesn't limit the groups to group **cluster** and sometimes the below playbook is run on localhost

```
- hosts: all:!localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    ...
```

The inventory file is below:

```
[localhost]
127.0.0.1  ansible_connection=local
[cluster]
ip1
ip2
ip3
```

Tried `- hosts: cluster`, however, play still runs on `localhost` sometimes.

There's option to limit the groups via [cli](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible/commands/#limit-to-one-or-more-hosts):

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/PLAYBOOK_NAME.yml --limit 'all:!localhost'
```

My goal is to  **limit groups a play is run** on from the playbook source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Ensure dir exists
  file:
    path: example/path
    state: directory
    owner: user
    group: group
    mode: 0755
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['cluster']
```

The following does the trick. It runs the task only on the group you wish.

```
when: inventory_hostname in groups['cluster']
```

Comment: thanks. however, what u showed is task limit, i need play limit

Answer (score 0):

Then either run on the desired group of hosts

```
    - hosts: cluster,cluster1,cluster2
      gather_facts: no
      tasks:
      ...
```

or in the inventories, you can group the groups of hosts by:

```
    [cluster]
    ip1
    ip2
    ip3

    [clusters:children]
    cluster
    cluster1
```

and then run the playbook on the *clusters* group